# What is the use of [0] in getFrom()[0]), used to get mail sender address

Tags: java

I know that `getFrom()` Returns the "From" attribute.

And If the "Sender" header field is absent, `null` is returned. This implementation uses the `getHeader` method to obtain the requisite header field.

But why using [0] with `getFrom()`. Using [1] throw exception "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1"

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Properties;

public class VerifyEmails {
    public Message message;
    public int count;
    public String result;

    public void check(String host, String user, String password) throws IOException, MessagingException {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.imap.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.imap.user", user);
        properties.put("mail.imap.port", "143");
        properties.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "false");
        Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties);
        Store store = emailSession.getStore("imap");
        store.connect(host, user, password);
        Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
        System.out.println("Total messages are---" + messages.length);
        for (count = 0; count < messages.length; count++) {
            message = messages[count];
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Email Number " + (count + 1));
            System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
            System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
            InputStream in = messages[count].getInputStream();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String read;
            while ((read = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(read);
            }
            br.close();
            String mailSource = sb.toString();
            System.out.println("mailSource is" + mailSource);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what type of variable does `getFrom` return?

Comment: What class are you talking about?

Comment: Can you add the code which includes the import statements?

Comment: paste the sample code here where you are facing issue

Comment: `[1]` means the second element of an array

Comment: please add some code to be specific :)

Answer (score 0):

Like explained in the method documentation  :

> This field contains the identity of the person(s)  who  wished
>           this  message to be sent.

You can have multiple persons in the from, which is the reason why you have an array. This [Stackoverflow thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/554520/smtp-allows-for-multiple-from-addresses-in-the-rfc-was-this-ever-useful-why-do)  talks about it.

But generally, you have only one person in this Array, wich is the reason why you have an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.